# XSLT1.0 Logic Grouping nodes

Tags: xslt

Input:

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <HEAD010->
      <Receiver>7612460142409</Receiver>
      <ASN>ASN</ASN>
      <Sender>8712423011212</Sender>
    </HEAD010->
    <HEAD020->
      <DeliveryNoteNumber>6125175001</DeliveryNoteNumber>
      <DeliveryNoteDate>2013-05-16</DeliveryNoteDate>
    </HEAD020->
    <HEAD030->
      <BookingTimestamp></BookingTimestamp>
      <BookingReference>F234</BookingReference>
    </HEAD030->
    <DELH030->
      <DeliveryAddressNumber></DeliveryAddressNumber>
    </DELH030->
    <DELH040->
      <CustomerName>Office Customer</CustomerName>
      <Address1>.</Address1>
    </DELH040->
    <DELH050->
      <Address2->Silbernstrasse 20</Address2->
      <City>CH-8953 Dietikon</City>
      <PostalCode>8953</PostalCode>
    </DELH050->
    <ITEM010->  <!--....... unbounded element.... -->
      <SupplierProductCode>4401896</SupplierProductCode>
      <ITEM020->
        <ItemDescription>FUSION LAMINATOR BUNDLE</ItemDescription>
      </ITEM020->
      <ITEM030->
        <EANItemCode>5028252380935</EANItemCode>
      </ITEM030->
      <ITEM040->
        <CustomerItemNumber>13627200</CustomerItemNumber>
      </ITEM040->  
      <ITEM060->
        <MovexOrderNumber>6125175</MovexOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>13/05/13</OrderDate>
      </ITEM060->
      <PACK010->
        <PackageType>PACKAGE/CARTON</PackageType>
      </PACK010->
      <PACK020->
        <PackageNumber>9797</PackageNumber>
      </PACK020->   
      <PACK050->
        <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber><!-- for each <PackNumber> if <PackNumber> we are performing logic  -->
      </PACK050->
    </ITEM010->

    <ITEM010->  <!--....... unbounded element.... -->
      <SupplierProductCode>4401896</SupplierProductCode>
      <ITEM020->
        <ItemDescription>FUSION LAMINATOR BUNDLE</ItemDescription>
      </ITEM020->
      <ITEM030->
        <EANItemCode>5028252312343</EANItemCode>
      </ITEM030->
      <ITEM040->
        <CustomerItemNumber>13627200</CustomerItemNumber>
      </ITEM040->  
      <ITEM060->
        <MovexOrderNumber>6125175</MovexOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>13/05/13</OrderDate>
      </ITEM060->
      <PACK010->
        <PackageType>PACKAGE/CARTON</PackageType>
      </PACK010->
      <PACK020->
        <PackageNumber>9797</PackageNumber>
      </PACK020->   
      <PACK050->
        <PackNumber>PLT9763411</PackNumber><!-- for each <PackNumber> if <PackNumber> we are performing logic  -->
      </PACK050->
    </ITEM010->


    <ITEM010->  <!--....... unbounded element.... -->
      <SupplierProductCode>4401896</SupplierProductCode>
      <ITEM020->
        <ItemDescription>FUSION LAMINATOR BUNDLE</ItemDescription>
      </ITEM020->
      <ITEM030->
        <EANItemCode>5028252888777</EANItemCode>
      </ITEM030->
      <ITEM040->
        <CustomerItemNumber>13627200</CustomerItemNumber>
      </ITEM040->  
      <ITEM060->
        <MovexOrderNumber>6125175</MovexOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>13/05/13</OrderDate>
      </ITEM060->
      <PACK010->
        <PackageType>PACKAGE/CARTON</PackageType>
      </PACK010->
      <PACK020->
        <PackageNumber>9797</PackageNumber>
      </PACK020->   
      <PACK050->
        <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber><!-- for each <PackNumber> if <PackNumber> we are performing logic  -->
      </PACK050->
    </ITEM010->

     <TAIL010->
      <NumberOfLines>4</NumberOfLines>
    </TAIL010->
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

for each   `<PackNumber>`  we are performing logic. If the `<PackNumber>` is different we have to increment the counter and the node belongs to the same `<PackNumber>`
comes under this counter.

output:

```
<A>
  <target>

    <d1>7612460142409</d1><!-- value of <Receiver> element -->
    <d2>81</d2><!-- Hard code value -->
    <d3>6125175001</d3> <!-- <DeliveryNoteNumber> value -->
    <d4>F234</d4><!-- <BookingReference> value -->
    <d5>Office Customer</d5><!-- <CustomerName> value -->
    <d6>102</d6><!--hard code value -->

    <!-- for-each <PackNumber> the following will come -->
    <CPS>
      <element1>2</element1><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count(starting from 2)-->
      <element2>1</element2><!-- hard code value-->
    </CPS>
    <PAC>
      <element4>111</element4><!-- hard code value-->
      <element5>012</element5><!-- hard code value-->
    </PAC>
    <LIN>
      <element6>1</element6><!-- sequence number start feom 1-->
      <element7>SV</element7><!-- hard code value-->
      <element8>5028252380935</element8><!-- <EANItemCode> -->
      <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
    </LIN>
    <!-- same <PackNumber> is present in two nodes so another LIN element also comes under same CPS elment  --> 
    <LIN>
      <element6>2</element6><!-- sequence number incremented-->
      <element7>SV</element7><!-- hard code value-->
      <element8>5028252888777</element8><!-- <EANItemCode> -->
      <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
    </LIN>

    <CPS>
      <element1>3</element1><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count-->
      <element2>1</element2><!-- hard code value-->
    </CPS>
    <PAC>
      <element4>111</element4><!-- hard code value-->
      <element5>012</element5><!-- hard code value-->
    </PAC>
    <LIN>
      <element6>3</element6><!-- sequence number incremented-->
      <element7>SV</element7><!-- hard code value-->
      <element8>5028252312343</element8><!-- <EANItemCode> -->
      <PackNumber>PLT9763411</PackNumber>
    </LIN>

  </target>
</A>
```