# XSLT 1.0 Logic grouping on nodes

Tags: xslt

input:

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <HEAD010->
      <Receiver>7612460142409</Receiver>
      <ASN>ASN</ASN>
      <Sender>8712423011212</Sender>
    </HEAD010->
    <HEAD020->
      <DeliveryNoteNumber>6125175001</DeliveryNoteNumber>
      <DeliveryNoteDate>2013-05-16</DeliveryNoteDate>
    </HEAD020->
    <HEAD030->
      <BookingTimestamp></BookingTimestamp>
      <BookingReference>F234</BookingReference>
    </HEAD030->
    <DELH030->
      <DeliveryAddressNumber></DeliveryAddressNumber>
    </DELH030->
    <DELH040->
      <CustomerName>Office Customer</CustomerName>
      <Address1>.</Address1>
    </DELH040->
    <DELH050->
      <Address2->Silbernstrasse 20</Address2->
      <City>CH-8953 Dietikon</City>
      <PostalCode>8953</PostalCode>
    </DELH050->
    <ITEM010->  <!--....... unbounded element.... -->
      <SupplierProductCode>4401896</SupplierProductCode>
      <ITEM020->
        <ItemDescription>FUSION LAMINATOR BUNDLE</ItemDescription>
      </ITEM020->
      <ITEM030->
        <EANItemCode>5028252380935</EANItemCode>
      </ITEM030->
      <ITEM040->
        <CustomerItemNumber>13627200</CustomerItemNumber>
      </ITEM040->  
      <ITEM060->
        <MovexOrderNumber>6125175</MovexOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>13/05/13</OrderDate>
      </ITEM060->
      <PACK010->
        <PackageType>PACKAGE/CARTON</PackageType>
      </PACK010->
      <PACK020->
        <PackageNumber>9797</PackageNumber>
      </PACK020->   
      <PACK050->
        <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber><!-- for each <PackNumber> if <PackNumber> we are performing logic  -->
      </PACK050->
    </ITEM010->

    <ITEM010->  <!--....... unbounded element.... -->
      <SupplierProductCode>4401896</SupplierProductCode>
      <ITEM020->
        <ItemDescription>FUSION LAMINATOR BUNDLE</ItemDescription>
      </ITEM020->
      <ITEM030->
        <EANItemCode>5028252312343</EANItemCode>
      </ITEM030->
      <ITEM040->
        <CustomerItemNumber>13627200</CustomerItemNumber>
      </ITEM040->  
      <ITEM060->
        <MovexOrderNumber>6125175</MovexOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>13/05/13</OrderDate>
      </ITEM060->
      <PACK010->
        <PackageType>PACKAGE/CARTON</PackageType>
      </PACK010->
      <PACK020->
        <PackageNumber>9797</PackageNumber>
      </PACK020->   
      <PACK050->
        <PackNumber>PLT9763411</PackNumber><!-- for each <PackNumber> if <PackNumber> we are performing logic  -->
      </PACK050->
    </ITEM010->


    <ITEM010->  <!--....... unbounded element.... -->
      <SupplierProductCode>4401896</SupplierProductCode>
      <ITEM020->
        <ItemDescription>FUSION LAMINATOR BUNDLE</ItemDescription>
      </ITEM020->
      <ITEM030->
        <EANItemCode>5028252888777</EANItemCode>
      </ITEM030->
      <ITEM040->
        <CustomerItemNumber>13627200</CustomerItemNumber>
      </ITEM040->  
      <ITEM060->
        <MovexOrderNumber>6125175</MovexOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>13/05/13</OrderDate>
      </ITEM060->
      <PACK010->
        <PackageType>PACKAGE/CARTON</PackageType>
      </PACK010->
      <PACK020->
        <PackageNumber>9797</PackageNumber>
      </PACK020->   
      <PACK050->
        <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber><!-- for each <PackNumber> if <PackNumber> we are performing logic  -->
      </PACK050->
    </ITEM010->

     <TAIL010->
      <NumberOfLines>4</NumberOfLines>
    </TAIL010->
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

for each `<PackNumber>` we are performing logic. If the `<PackNumber>` is different we have to increment the counter and the node belongs to the same `<PackNumber>` comes under this counter.

```
output:
<A>
  <target>

    <d1>7612460142409</d1><!-- value of <Receiver> element -->
    <d2>81</d2><!-- Hard code value -->
    <d3>6125175001</d3> <!-- <DeliveryNoteNumber> value -->
    <d4>F234</d4><!-- <BookingReference> value -->
    <d5>Office Customer</d5><!-- <CustomerName> value -->
    <d6>102</d6><!--hard code value -->

    <!-- for-each <PackNumber> the following will come -->
    <CPS>
      <element1>2</element1><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count(starting from 2)-->
      <element2>1</element2><!-- hard code value-->
    </CPS>
    <PAC>
      <element4>111</element4><!-- hard code value-->
      <element5>012</element5><!-- hard code value-->
    </PAC>
    <LIN>
      <element6>1</element6><!-- sequence number start feom 1-->
      <element7>SV</element7><!-- hard code value-->
      <element8>5028252380935</element8><!-- <EANItemCode> -->
      <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
    </LIN>
    <!-- same <PackNumber> is present in two nodes so another LIN element also comes under same CPS elment  --> 
    <LIN>
      <element6>2</element6><!-- sequence number incremented-->
      <element7>SV</element7><!-- hard code value-->
      <element8>5028252888777</element8><!-- <EANItemCode> -->
      <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
    </LIN>

    <CPS>
      <element1>3</element1><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count-->
      <element2>1</element2><!-- hard code value-->
    </CPS>
    <PAC>
      <element4>111</element4><!-- hard code value-->
      <element5>012</element5><!-- hard code value-->
    </PAC>
    <LIN>
      <element6>3</element6><!-- sequence number incremented-->
      <element7>SV</element7><!-- hard code value-->
      <element8>5028252312343</element8><!-- <EANItemCode> -->
      <PackNumber>PLT9763411</PackNumber>
    </LIN>

  </target>
</A>
```

Update input:

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <HEAD010->
      <Receiver>7612460142409</Receiver>
      <ASN>ASN</ASN>
      <Sender>8712423011212</Sender>
    </HEAD010->
    <HEAD020->
      <DeliveryNoteNumber>6125175001</DeliveryNoteNumber>
      <DeliveryNoteDate>2013-05-16</DeliveryNoteDate>
    </HEAD020->
    <HEAD030->
      <BookingTimestamp></BookingTimestamp>
      <BookingReference>F234</BookingReference>
    </HEAD030->
    <DELH030->
      <DeliveryAddressNumber></DeliveryAddressNumber>
    </DELH030->
    <DELH040->
      <CustomerName>Office Customer</CustomerName>
      <Address1>.</Address1>
    </DELH040->
    <DELH050->
      <Address2->Silbernstrasse 20</Address2->
      <City>CH-8953 Dietikon</City>
      <PostalCode>8953</PostalCode>
    </DELH050->
    <ITEM010->  <!--....... unbounded element.... -->
      <SupplierProductCode>4401896</SupplierProductCode>
      <ITEM020->
        <ItemDescription>FUSION LAMINATOR BUNDLE</ItemDescription>
      </ITEM020->
      <ITEM030->
        <EANItemCode>5028252380935</EANItemCode>
      </ITEM030->
      <ITEM040->
        <CustomerItemNumber>13627200</CustomerItemNumber>
      </ITEM040->  
      <ITEM060->
        <MovexOrderNumber>6125175</MovexOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>13/05/13</OrderDate>
      </ITEM060->
      <PACK010->
        <PackageType>PACKAGE/CARTON</PackageType>
      </PACK010->
      <PACK020->
        <PackageNumber>9797</PackageNumber>
      </PACK020->   
      <PACK050->
        <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber><!-- for each <PackNumber> if <PackNumber> we are performing logic  -->
      </PACK050->
    </ITEM010->

    <ITEM010->  <!--....... unbounded element.... -->
      <SupplierProductCode>4401896</SupplierProductCode>
      <ITEM020->
        <ItemDescription>FUSION LAMINATOR BUNDLE</ItemDescription>
      </ITEM020->
      <ITEM030->
        <EANItemCode>5028252312343</EANItemCode>
      </ITEM030->
      <ITEM040->
        <CustomerItemNumber>13627200</CustomerItemNumber>
      </ITEM040->  
      <ITEM060->
        <MovexOrderNumber>6125175</MovexOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>13/05/13</OrderDate>
      </ITEM060->
      <PACK010->
        <PackageType>PACKAGE/CARTON</PackageType>
      </PACK010->
      <PACK020->
        <PackageNumber>9797</PackageNumber>
      </PACK020->   
      <PACK050->
        <PackNumber/><!-- for each <PackNumber> if <PackNumber> we are performing logic  -->
      </PACK050->
    </ITEM010->


    <ITEM010->  <!--....... unbounded element.... -->
      <SupplierProductCode>4401896</SupplierProductCode>
      <ITEM020->
        <ItemDescription>FUSION LAMINATOR BUNDLE</ItemDescription>
      </ITEM020->
      <ITEM030->
        <EANItemCode>5028252888777</EANItemCode>
      </ITEM030->
      <ITEM040->
        <CustomerItemNumber>13627200</CustomerItemNumber>
      </ITEM040->  
      <ITEM060->
        <MovexOrderNumber>6125175</MovexOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>13/05/13</OrderDate>
      </ITEM060->
      <PACK010->
        <PackageType>PACKAGE/CARTON</PackageType>
      </PACK010->
      <PACK020->
        <PackageNumber>9797</PackageNumber>
      </PACK020->   
      <PACK050->
        <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber><!-- for each <PackNumber> if <PackNumber> we are performing logic  -->
      </PACK050->
    </ITEM010->

     <TAIL010->
      <NumberOfLines>4</NumberOfLines>
    </TAIL010->
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

update output:

```
<A>
      <target>

        <d1>7612460142409</d1><!-- value of <Receiver> element -->
        <d2>81</d2><!-- Hard code value -->
        <d3>6125175001</d3> <!-- <DeliveryNoteNumber> value -->
        <d4>F234</d4><!-- <BookingReference> value -->
        <d5>Office Customer</d5><!-- <CustomerName> value -->
        <d6>102</d6><!--hard code value -->

        <!-- for-each <PackNumber> the following will come -->
        <CPS>
          <element1>2</element1><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count(starting from 2)-->
          <element2>1</element2><!-- hard code value-->
        </CPS>
        <PAC>
          <element4>111</element4><!-- hard code value-->
          <element5>012</element5><!-- hard code value-->
        </PAC>
        <LIN>
          <element6>1</element6><!-- sequence number start feom 1-->
          <element7>SV</element7><!-- hard code value-->
          <element8>5028252380935</element8><!-- <EANItemCode> -->
          <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
        </LIN>
        <!-- same <PackNumber> is present in two nodes so another LIN element also comes under same CPS elment  --> 
        <LIN>
          <element6>2</element6><!-- sequence number incremented-->
          <element7>SV</element7><!-- hard code value-->
          <element8>5028252888777</element8><!-- <EANItemCode> -->
          <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
        </LIN>

        <CPS>
          <element1>3</element1><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count-->
          <element2>1</element2><!-- hard code value-->
        </CPS>
        <PAC>
          <element4>111</element4><!-- hard code value-->
          <element5>012</element5><!-- hard code value-->
        </PAC>
        <LIN>
          <element6>3</element6><!-- sequence number incremented-->
          <element7>SV</element7><!-- hard code value-->
          <element8>5028252312343</element8><!-- <EANItemCode> -->
          <PackNumber/>
        </LIN>

      </target>
    </A>
```

Comment: Have you created any XSLT stuffs to generate this output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT1.0 Logic Grouping nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807094/xslt1-0-logic-grouping-nodes)

Comment: In that post there i did not get proper answer,so i have posted again as a new post.

Comment: If you don't get suitable answers the correct thing to do is _edit_ the existing question to add any necessary clarifications, you should definitely not post exactly the same question again with no link back to the previous version.

Comment: @sum: Editing your previous question is exactly what I advised you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shows you how you may accomplish this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns=""
>
  <!-- Define a key so that we can fetch all packnumber nodes given a packnumber -->
  <xsl:key name="packnrs" match="//PackNumber" use="text()"/>

  <xsl:template match="Move-Afile">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Afile" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Afile">
    <xsl:copy>

      <!-- Call process-packnrs with a set of all unique packnumbers -->
      <xsl:call-template name="process-packnrs">
        <xsl:with-param name="packnrs" select="//PackNumber[generate-id() = generate-id(key('packnrs', .)[1])]" />
      </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="process-packnrs">
    <xsl:param name="count" select="2" />
    <xsl:param name="packnrs" />
    <xsl:param name="pos" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="seq" select="0" />

    <xsl:variable name="packnr" select="$packnrs[$pos]" />

    <CPS>
      <element1><xsl:value-of select="$count"/></element1>
      <element2>1</element2>
    </CPS>

    <!-- Do work for this pack number -->
    <xsl:for-each select="key('packnrs', $packnr)">

      <LIN>
        <element6><xsl:value-of select="$seq + position()" /></element6>
        <PackNumber><xsl:value-of select="." /></PackNumber>
      </LIN>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- Call for the next pack number -->
    <xsl:if test="$pos &lt; count($packnrs)">
      <xsl:call-template name="process-packnrs">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="packnrs" select="$packnrs" />
        <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="seq" select="$seq + count(key('packnrs', $packnr))" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Play with it on xsltcake [here](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/JT7zgL/2).

Comment: <LIN>
      <element6>1</element6> this value is not coming properly please chk

Comment: this should be a sequence number starts from 1

Comment: I added the sequence count, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: in case  IF PackNumber is NULL  like  <PackNumber/> in any one of the node we have to consider  that one also as different one and CPS count $count gets incremented.Pls modify the same.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet will do as you ask. It uses a `key` together with `generate-id` to all the `ITEM010-` elements that are first for each `PackNumber`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="item-by-packnumber" match="ITEM010-" use="PACK050-/PackNumber"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Move-Afile/Afile"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Afile">
    <A>
      <target>
        <d1><xsl:value-of select="HEAD010-/Receiver"/></d1>
        <d2>81</d2>
        <d3><xsl:value-of select="HEAD020-/DeliveryNoteNumber"/></d3>
        <d4><xsl:value-of select="HEAD030-/BookingReference"/></d4>
        <d5><xsl:value-of select="DELH040-/CustomerName"/></d5>
        <d6>102</d6>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM010-[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-packnumber', PACK050-/PackNumber)[1])]"/>
      </target>
    </A>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM010-">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="group" select="key('item-by-packnumber', PACK050-/PackNumber)">
      <xsl:with-param name="sequence" select="2+count(preceding-sibling::ITEM010-[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-packnumber', PACK050-/PackNumber)[1])])"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM010-" mode="group">
    <xsl:param name="sequence"/>
    <CPS>
      <element1><xsl:value-of select="$sequence"/></element1>
      <element2>1</element2>
    </CPS>
    <PAC>
      <element4>111</element4>
      <element5>012</element5>
    </PAC>
    <LIN>
      <element6><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></element6>
      <element7>SV</element7>
      <element8><xsl:value-of select="ITEM030-/EANItemCode"/></element8>
      <xsl:copy-of select="PACK050-/PackNumber"/>
    </LIN>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<A>
   <target>
      <d1>7612460142409</d1>
      <d2>81</d2>
      <d3>6125175001</d3>
      <d4>F234</d4>
      <d5>Office Customer</d5>
      <d6>102</d6>
      <CPS>
         <element1>2</element1>
         <element2>1</element2>
      </CPS>
      <PAC>
         <element4>111</element4>
         <element5>012</element5>
      </PAC>
      <LIN>
         <element6>1</element6>
         <element7>SV</element7>
         <element8>5028252380935</element8>
         <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
      </LIN>
      <CPS>
         <element1>2</element1>
         <element2>1</element2>
      </CPS>
      <PAC>
         <element4>111</element4>
         <element5>012</element5>
      </PAC>
      <LIN>
         <element6>2</element6>
         <element7>SV</element7>
         <element8>5028252888777</element8>
         <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
      </LIN>
      <CPS>
         <element1>3</element1>
         <element2>1</element2>
      </CPS>
      <PAC>
         <element4>111</element4>
         <element5>012</element5>
      </PAC>
      <LIN>
         <element6>1</element6>
         <element7>SV</element7>
         <element8>5028252312343</element8>
         <PackNumber>PLT9763411</PackNumber>
      </LIN>
   </target>
</A>
```

---

**Update**

This alternative works better, and produces the exact XML output that you require. However it is a little ungainly and uses the EXSLT `node-set` function which you may not have access to.

It works by sorting the `ITEM010-` elements into variable `$items` and working from the data there using `exslt:node-set($items)` instead of directly from the source.

Others may be able to suggest a better alternative.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="item-by-packnumber" match="ITEM010-" use="PACK050-/PackNumber"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Move-Afile/Afile"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Afile">

    <xsl:variable name="items">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM010-" mode="copy">
        <xsl:sort select="PACK050-/PackNumber"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <A>
      <target>
        <d1><xsl:value-of select="HEAD010-/Receiver"/></d1>
        <d2>81</d2>
        <d3><xsl:value-of select="HEAD020-/DeliveryNoteNumber"/></d3>
        <d4><xsl:value-of select="HEAD030-/BookingReference"/></d4>
        <d5><xsl:value-of select="DELH040-/CustomerName"/></d5>
        <d6>102</d6>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($items)/ITEM010-"/>
      </target>
    </A>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM010-">

    <xsl:variable name="first-in-sequence" select="generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-packnumber', PACK050-/PackNumber)[1])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="group" select="2+count(preceding-sibling::ITEM010-[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-packnumber', PACK050-/PackNumber)[1])])"/>

    <xsl:if test="$first-in-sequence">
      <CPS>
        <element1><xsl:value-of select="$group"/></element1>
        <element2>1</element2>
      </CPS>
      <PAC>
        <element4>111</element4>
        <element5>012</element5>
      </PAC>
    </xsl:if>

    <LIN>
      <element6><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></element6>
      <element7>SV</element7>
      <element8><xsl:value-of select="ITEM030-/EANItemCode"/></element8>
      <xsl:copy-of select="PACK050-/PackNumber"/>
    </LIN>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<A>
   <target>
      <d1>7612460142409</d1>
      <d2>81</d2>
      <d3>6125175001</d3>
      <d4>F234</d4>
      <d5>Office Customer</d5>
      <d6>102</d6>
      <CPS>
         <element1>2</element1>
         <element2>1</element2>
      </CPS>
      <PAC>
         <element4>111</element4>
         <element5>012</element5>
      </PAC>
      <LIN>
         <element6>1</element6>
         <element7>SV</element7>
         <element8>5028252380935</element8>
         <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
      </LIN>
      <LIN>
         <element6>2</element6>
         <element7>SV</element7>
         <element8>5028252888777</element8>
         <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
      </LIN>
      <CPS>
         <element1>3</element1>
         <element2>1</element2>
      </CPS>
      <PAC>
         <element4>111</element4>
         <element5>012</element5>
      </PAC>
      <LIN>
         <element6>3</element6>
         <element7>SV</element7>
         <element8>5028252312343</element8>
         <PackNumber>PLT9763411</PackNumber>
      </LIN>
   </target>
</A>
```

Comment: under the  <CPS>
         <element1>2</element1>
         <element2>1</element2>
      </CPS> my output contains  two LIN elements because the PackNumber is same.Please check.

Comment: if  PackNumber is equal we have to ignore the repeating of <CPS>,<PAC> elements.only one time it comes.

Comment: @sum: Yes, I understand. And you want the output data sorted by `PackNumber`? The difficulty I have is producing the sequence number in `element6` according to the *output* order while grouping the elements at the same time. Do you have access to the EXSLT `node-set` function?

Comment: yes i want the output sorted by PackNumber.ok please  suggest EXSLT way.

Comment: @sum: I have added a stylesheet that will work correctly using the extended XSLT function `node-set` so that the data can be sorted before it is processed.

Comment: @sum: Then I can't help you any further. It may be an idea to update your question to say that you still need an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought I suggest this stylesheet, which works with XSLT 1.0 and doesn't use the EXSLT `node-set` function. It's a little awkward, but is probably the best you will get. It works by having the template for `ITEM010-` nodes pplying itself recursively, and calculating the sequence and group numbers from the size of each group.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="item-by-packnumber" match="ITEM010-" use="PACK050-/PackNumber"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Move-Afile/Afile"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Afile">

    <A>
      <target>
        <d1><xsl:value-of select="HEAD010-/Receiver"/></d1>
        <d2>81</d2>
        <d3><xsl:value-of select="HEAD020-/DeliveryNoteNumber"/></d3>
        <d4><xsl:value-of select="HEAD030-/BookingReference"/></d4>
        <d5><xsl:value-of select="DELH040-/CustomerName"/></d5>
        <d6>102</d6>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM010-[1]"/>
      </target>
    </A>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM010-">
    <xsl:param name="offset" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="group" select="2"/>

    <CPS>
      <element1><xsl:value-of select="$group"/></element1>
      <element2>1</element2>
    </CPS>
    <PAC>
      <element4>111</element4>
      <element5>012</element5>
    </PAC>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('item-by-packnumber', PACK050-/PackNumber)" mode="group">
      <xsl:with-param name="offset" select="$offset"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ITEM010-[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-packnumber', PACK050-/PackNumber)[1])]">
      <xsl:with-param name="offset" select="$offset + count(key('item-by-packnumber', PACK050-/PackNumber))"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="group" select="$group + 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM010-" mode="group">
    <xsl:param name="offset"/>
    <LIN>
      <element6><xsl:value-of select="position()+$offset"/></element6>
      <element7>SV</element7>
      <element8><xsl:value-of select="ITEM030-/EANItemCode"/></element8>
      <PackNumber><xsl:value-of select="PACK050-/PackNumber"/></PackNumber>
    </LIN>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<A>
   <target>
      <d1>7612460142409</d1>
      <d2>81</d2>
      <d3>6125175001</d3>
      <d4>F234</d4>
      <d5>Office Customer</d5>
      <d6>102</d6>
      <CPS>
         <element1>2</element1>
         <element2>1</element2>
      </CPS>
      <PAC>
         <element4>111</element4>
         <element5>012</element5>
      </PAC>
      <LIN>
         <element6>1</element6>
         <element7>SV</element7>
         <element8>5028252380935</element8>
         <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
      </LIN>
      <LIN>
         <element6>2</element6>
         <element7>SV</element7>
         <element8>5028252888777</element8>
         <PackNumber>PLT9180267</PackNumber>
      </LIN>
      <CPS>
         <element1>3</element1>
         <element2>1</element2>
      </CPS>
      <PAC>
         <element4>111</element4>
         <element5>012</element5>
      </PAC>
      <LIN>
         <element6>3</element6>
         <element7>SV</element7>
         <element8>5028252312343</element8>
         <PackNumber>PLT9763411</PackNumber>
      </LIN>
   </target>
</A>
```